# Adding normal graph on memory usage per process to Zabbix

Tags: linux, monitoring, process, memory-usage

I need to monitor memory usage per process of processes on Linux. My monitoring tool is Zabbix. I found some links which describe how we can do it on windows. As an example I can refer to [Host processes monitoring-graphs LLD](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=26987)
But how can I have a graph in which memory usage of processes of a Linux system is shown? If useful my Linux distribution is Debian.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an  OOB key for both passive and active agent that does this, just  create the item in your applicable hosts!

Once you create the item, you have to manually create the graph.

If you have many Linux hosts to apply this to, you may add the item and graph to a template and assign it to ask relevant hosts.

I am referencing Zabbix 2.4.4